# Can you use Magic to Defend? Fate Core rules in a Dresden Files universe

Tags: fate, dresden-files, fate-core

The annotation on YS253 says that you can't use a Block or Counterspell as a defense action.

But as in Fate Core's [four actions](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions), it makes sense that it's always possible to use magic to [defend](https://fate-srd.com/fate-core/four-actions#defend), rolling Discipline just like any other skill.

In that case, I'm considering the Practitioner will use a simple Evocation (and so, incur mental stress) to define an *armor rating* instead of *weapon rating* like how it works for attacks:

- if he surpasses the attack roll, he succeeds in deflecting the attack.
- if he doesn't surpass the attack but still succeeds in the Discipline roll for controlling the spell, he gets hit but still has the *armor rating* to reduce the stress inflicted by the attack
- if he fails on the Discipline (control) roll he must deal with *backslash or fallout* prior to resolving the action.

The caveats on this are:

1. Rules become too complicated (by adding *armor ratings* to defense rolls).
2. This would make attack spells less effective (or less dangerous), probably causing a lot of ties during conflicts.
3. A successful defense roll makes the *armor rating* useless, so it would be just simpler to buy a *use Discipline to defend against Magic* Stunt or even allow all Practitioners to do that for free.

So, what would be the best option to *defend with magic* in DFRPG?

Comment: Are you in fact using Fate Core rules in DFRPG, or are you just referring to Fate Core for inspiration? (DFRPG is not fully compatible with Fate Core, so which you're doing makes a difference.)

Comment: To expand on what SSD is saying: Fate Core is effectively Fate version 3, and Dresden Files is Fate version 2-point-something. Fate Core came with some significant revision to various rules that don't exist in DFRPG, and Fate variants are free to modify how things work anyway. The primary source for how things work in DFRPG is DFRPG itself; Fate Core is a later, separate product and using its rules effectively means using house rules.

Comment: "it makes sense that it's always possible to use magic to defend" — It doesn't make sense according to the rules established by the fiction of the Dresen Files setting, which always show magical defences as having been prepared in advance.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yes, I'm using FATE Core rules. Basically the _Four Outcomes_ and _Four Actions_, cause they're easier to understand and manage.

Comment: I don't feel like the question being asked here has been answered in the other question, but I also feel like the answer to the question being asked here would be opinion-based because it's asking for a house rule (it's not in Fate Core).

Comment: Would it be possible to unmark this as a duplicate? This OP is using a different system than the linked question.

Comment: Well, as I see, the short answer is **no**, but there are a few options for reactive magical defense with minor prep, and they're not exactly _house rules_. For example, it could be done using an enchanted item or triggered Thaumaturgy spell (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/34898/dresden-rpg-thaumaturgy-conditional-triggers).

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  It's asking how the Fate Core rules handle defense with magic -- note that blocks do not exist in Fate Core, and there is, in fact, established practice on how you "block" someone from doing things in FC).

Comment: Some thoughts here http://www.faterpg.com/2013/blocks-and-borders-live-in-fate-core/

Comment: Also, as someone said me on the chat room. A block is intended to prevent a simple kind of action, for example, if a character stand in front of an opponent to prevent him from running, any attempt to run on that direction should win a contest or overcome a defined difficulty. So, a Block can easily be done in FATE Core with _Create an Advantage_. If the oponnent acts dirrectly against that advantage it should overcome it's difficulty.
Its more open and less detailed, but it can still work.